# Classpath in a Java Web Start application

Tags: java, classpath, java-web-start

I need to load an .xml file in META-INF, it works when the application isn't sandboxed, but in Java Web Start a different classloader (which is more restricted) seems to be used, so the file found in myproj.jar/META-INF/myfile.xml isn't loaded. It however works if I put the file in the current directory of the loading class (I put it under com/blabla/myproj/whatever/META-INF/myfile.xml).

I couldn't find any classpath settings within the .jnlp file, but perhaps this can be done with a manifest? I don't know how they work, so if that's the solution please supply an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuff in `META-INF` should *not* be readable by code in your jar file, since that code should be agnostic to the fact that it's packaged in a JAR.  Instead, since it is *meta information* (meta-inf) about the Jar itself, only the application that *loads* the jar file should access it.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Do you know where I should put the .xml files in Eclipse and where they end up in the .jar? And how I load 'em?

Comment: @Jonas: If you simply put them in the same folder as your Java files, Eclipse will probably copy them to the Jar for you (and they will be on the classpath).  In the Jar, it will be packaged just like a class file (`/com/yourcompany/package/yourfile.xml`).  So put it in the correct place in your package structure.  Another common organization is to have a separate "resources" folder that parallels the package structure, but then you would have to configure Eclipse to copy the resources into the Jar file.  It's been a while since I've used Eclipse so you'd have to poke around to figure out how.